# Режим компиляции SNMP приложения

Tags: linux, snmp

При попытке собрать на Linux простейшее приложения с библиотекой Net-SNMP (открыть сессию и закрыть сессию - всё) выдается такая ошибка

```
/usr/include/net-snmp/library/snmp_api.h:706:8: error: unknown type name ‘netsnmp_transport’
```

Я предполагаю, что либо какой-то флаг компиляции не указал, либо како-то инклюдник не подключил.

По сути, программа из пяти строк:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/session_api.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct snmp_session s;
    void * session;
    // Выполняем инициализацию переменных
    snmp_sess_init(&s);
    session = snmp_sess_open(&s);

    // Закрываем сессию
    rc = snmp_sess_close(&s);
    if (rc == 0) {
        printf("Неудачное завершение сессии\n");
    } else {
        printf("Программа завершилась нормально\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Может кто-то объяснить - в чём причина ситуации ?

Comment: судя по https://github.com/haad/net-snmp: `#include <net-snmp/library/snmp_transport.h>`

Comment: @alexander barakin Спасибо - помогло!

Comment: @alexander_barakin  Но в какой доке это написано ?! Я думаю, что это не последняя "закорючка".

Comment: понятия не имею. я всего лишь поискал упоминания в исходниках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[описание типа *netsnmp_transport*](https://github.com/haad/net-snmp/blob/c629882ba31aaf27c859de2d47a6401849661ccd/include/net-snmp/library/snmp_transport.h#L109) в файле `snmp_transport.h`:

```
typedef struct netsnmp_transport_s {
...
} netsnmp_transport;
```

---

```
$ apt-file search snmp_transport.h
libsnmp-dev: /usr/include/net-snmp/library/snmp_transport.h
```

---

подключение:

```
#include <net-snmp/library/snmp_transport.h>
```